# Sensitivity of Wheatstone bridge

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I was going through my textbook and it told me that the sensitivity of a metre bridge is maximum when the resistances in its arms are equal (at balanced conditions) and for a potentiometer if the balance point is obtained closer to one of the ends. Also, it's mentioned that the current from the driver cell is kept constant using a rheostat. Why? Could someone provide me with a detailed explanation using a derivation and possibly a graph? I'm only in 12th and I've seen several derivations on the internet but can't understand them thoroughly.

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. Do you think you could a) provide a reference to your textbook, b) define what you mean by "sensitivity", and c) split out the constant current question as separate? Because right now, while it's possible to write an answer, it would be hard to give a good answer that is understandable to other visitors of the site without doing a lot of the work you should be doing.

Comment: I found an online copy of a textbook called Pradeep's. By sensitivity I mean the accuracy with which the metre bridge measures the unknown resistance. I didn't want to flood the site with questions and since these questions have sort of the same underlying principle behind them, I grouped them. Sorry if I did wrong.